# Long time for resetting procedure in iPhone 6

Tags: restore, iphone

I am resetting my iPhone 6 (Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings) and it is taking a very long time.

I have tried holding the middle button and on & off button but it just results in going back to the white screen with the black apple and the loading bar. The loading bar is loading a milimeter across and has not moved for over an hour!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the Home Button and Power button for at least 10 seconds, once you see the Apple Logo (after the 10 seconds) let go.
If this doesn't work you might have to restore in DFU mode, otherwise try contacting Apple Support (if possible, to try to save you the trouble of a restore). If not, I can give instructions on Restoring in DFU mode.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to perform a soft reset, or are you trying to wipe the device? If it is stuck on the reset bar after doing a soft reset, try doing a soft reset again.

Comment: Not a full wipe or soft reset, the OP is just resetting all settings..

Comment: Have you tried another soft reset by holding down the power button and home button until you see the Apple logo again?